# Theorem 8.2 Rudin and its application

Tags: real-analysis

This is Rudin's Proof of theorem 8.2 and its application to prove Abel's Theorem. I have some questions about this.

First, what's the intuition behind this theorem? My understanding is that we know power series converges absolutely within radius of convergence, but we do not know what will happen at the endpoint, this theorem shows under certain conditions f is continuous at the endpoint.

Second question is equation (10), why do we need to restrict x to [0,1)? I think $f(x)*g(x)=h(x)$ always holds regardless of the value of x, and we directly plug x=1 in, we get the result.

Comment: You can set from the begining that f is defined at 1. As the sum of $c_n$ converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, a power series converges absolutely within its radius of convergence $R$, but it is not at all clear whether $\sum c_n x^n$ converges for $x  = \pm R$. The theorem says that (in case $R = 1$), that **if** $\sum c_n$ converges, then the function $f : (-1,1] \to \mathbb R, f(x) = \sum c_n x^n$, is *continuous* in $x = 1$. This is non-trivial although we know that $f(1)$ is well-defined.

For (10): You can of course multiply $f(1)$ and $g(1)$, but a priori  you do not know that $f(1)\cdot g(1) = h(1)$. But for $\lvert x \rvert < 1$ we have $f(x)\cdot g(x) = h(x)$ because we know how to multiply two power series having the same radius of convergence: *Within* the radius of convergence we get the power series $h$.